# Select query truncates numeric data greater than 10 digits

Tags: csv, ms-access, ms-jet-ace

I am trying to find a solution to this for few days without any success. Would really appreciate any help

I am trying to import a csv file into an Access database but some data from a numeric column gets truncated.

I do not have MS Access installed in my machine(only the windows preinstalled jet database engine (`msjet40.dll and msjetoledb40.dll`)). But everything else works fine except this issue. I am using `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` in the connection string.

The csv file contains numeric as well as non numeric columns in the file. As long as the numeric column in question has value less than around `2140649050` it selects fine.

```
SELECT * into ds1 FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & LFPath & "].[" & LFName & "]
```

Initially i assumed the truncation of data happens while loading data to the table. But the data gets truncated at the time of select itself. The below select query returns part of the data truncated for the UPC column

```
SELECT HeadName,[upc code],len([upc code]) as maxlen  FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & LFPath & "].[" & LFName & "]
```

Here is the output for the same

```
HeadName    upc code    maxlen
TOTAL U.S   2140649030  10
TOTAL U.S   2140649050  10
TOTAL U.S   2140649050  10
TOTAL U.S       
TOTAL U.S       
TOTAL U.S       
TOTAL U.S       
TOTAL U.S
```

Seems it sets the maxlength of the column based on the initial few records. How can i prevent it from doing that.

Access is opted because of no extra setup is required for the tool to run in windows.

The data is not truncated when MS Access is installed(Tested with Access 2010). Does that mean `ACE.OLEDB.12` works better with latest ACE egine `ACECORE.dll` ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine))

Please suggest any possibilities to fix the problem without the extra load of installing other versions of database

Comment: Try using a [schema.ini](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(VS.85).aspx) file to explicitly define what the column types should be. It looks like the Text driver is assuming that the column is Long Integer and truncating values that exceed the maximum value of a signed 32-bit integer (~2.1E9).

Comment: The column counts are not fixed for the data file. so the only option i see right now is to sort the file in descending order based on this column and then load. But i wonder if it is possible to sort the actual csv file itself from vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i could see and research i found 2 options we can go with. Both involves an additional step.

First option would be to **sort the csv file in descending order of the column**. In my case only one column was getting truncated. So i could sort the list based on the particular column in descending order and the data gets inserted without truncation. (could not find an automated solution to sort a file programatically. so we need to manually sort the file and then load to database)

The other option is to **convert the csv file into an excel file** and use the same to load the data. Here is the [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655294/import-excel-spreadsheet-into-ms-access-database) for the same

Answer (score 0):

you can try formatting cells to general? then might be your data will not truncate.

Comment: The file will be having varying column counts which restricts from fixing the issue in the file