# Import Excel spreadsheet into MS Access Database

Tags: excel, ms-access, import

Similar to this [post](http://Import%20Excel%20spreadsheet%20columns%20into%20SQL%20Server%20database) I need to import data from excel spreadsheet to a new access table using a query

Is there something similar to this query for importing to access database

```
INSERT INTO [tblTemp] ([Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4])

SELECT A.[Column1], A.[Column2], A.[Column3], A.[Column4]
FROM OPENROWSET 
('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\Excel.xls;HDR=YES', 'select * from [Sheet1$]') AS A;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use query like this:

```
SELECT [Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4] 
INTO [tblTemp] 
FROM [Worsheet1$A2:D122] IN 'D:\Excel.xls' [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0] 
WHERE [Column1] is Not Null;
```

Comment: wow awsome !! I could do this for the entire sheet in xlsx..      "SELECT *
FROM [sheet1$] IN 'D:\Data_Pull_FINAL.xlsx' [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0]

Comment: I am running the query on a different closed excel file. While running the query it opens the file too. can i prevent this?

Comment: Never mind. Fixed it like this  `"Set objfile = Workbooks.Open(StrFile1)

StrSql = "SELECT * into tmp FROM [" & objfile.Sheets(1).Name & "$] IN '" & StrFile1 & "' [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0]"
Con.Execute StrSql
objfile.Close False`

Comment: With the parameters in a different order this format also works: `FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=C:\Filename.xlsx].[Sheet1$];`