# Linkless path to an Excel workbook in MS Access 2016

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Instead of using linked tables, I now create a query in this format:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable IN 'S:\NetworkShare\Folder\MyAccessDB.accdb'
```

This gives me the advantage of using a QueryDef object to control the path to any recordset if it ever changes.  This can be done without linking tables which seems to be more rigid and less dynamic.

Is it possible to do this with a linked Excel Workbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `QueryDef` can have this format:

```
SELECT * FROM [SheetName$Range] IN 'FilePath' [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1]
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=FilePath].[SheetName$Range]
```

If the first row of your data is the header, then `HDR=YES` else `HDR=NO`

`IMEX` (Import Export Mode) can have 3 [values](https://www.tutorialfor.com/blog-196902.htm) `0, 1 and 2`

- 0 - Export Mode (Write)
- 1 - Import Mode (Read)
- 2 - Linked Mode (Read + Write)

For `.xls` file format, Excel 97 up till Excel 2003, use `Excel 8.0`.

For `.xlsx` file format, Excel 2007 and later, use `Excel 12.0 Xml`.

See this [site](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/) for other connection options.

`Range` is optional, if your data is fixed it can be `A1:D50`. If your columns are fixed but rows are not, you can use `A1:D` which will read until the last row.

E.g.
Your file path is `C:\User\UserName\Data\File1.xlsx` with `Sheet1` and the first row contains the header, then your `QueryDef` can be:

```
SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=C:\User\UserName\Data\File1.xlsx].[Sheet1$]
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] IN 'C:\User\UserName\Data\File1.xlsx' [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1]
```

See this related question also [Import Excel spreadsheet into MS Access Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655294/import-excel-spreadsheet-into-ms-access-database)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something similar with [ADODB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/168336/how-to-open-ado-connection-and-recordset-objects), for example

```
Dim YourFilePath As String
YourFilePath = "Your\file\path"

Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

Dim objConnection As Object
Dim objRecordset As Object

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Application.StatusBar = "Connecting To DataSource"

objConnection.Mode = 1
objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Mode=Read;" & _
    "Data Source=" & YourFilePath & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

Application.StatusBar = "Querying DataSource"

'HERE IS YOUR SELECT QUERY
objRecordset.Open "Select * FROM [Sheet1$A1:Z10000]", _
    objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    
Do Until objRecordset.EOF
    Dim someCellValue as String

    'GET YOUR DATA FROM HERE
    someCellValue = objRecordset.Fields.Item("ColumnName")

    'MOVE TO NEXT ROW
    objRecordset.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Will this still work like a QDF?  I've built queries based on the Excel workbook.  If any of the folder structures change, I've written code to adapt the new structure - except for the linked Excel.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by QDF? If the folder structure that your Excel workbook is in changes, you will have to update `YourFilePath`

Comment: Sorry, that's a variable, I meant QueryDef.   That query which refers to my Excel would be called something like qMyExcel, enabling me to use Select qMyExcel IN 'T:\NewPath\Folder\ActualWorkbook.xlsx'.   The qMyExcel would  seem permanent.  Then if the database should not find it, it would simply ask the user.